# Minecraft Mob behaviour

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands

I was wondering if it's possible to control what zombies do. Is it possible to make the zombies attack certain players but not attack other players? I haven't tried anything yet because I'm guessing this will require /scoreboard and I know nothing of this command. I'm on 1.7.10 minecraft and I'm wanting to do this in vanilla minecraft.

Comment: You should give a bit more info. Have you tried anything allready? Have you done online research?

Comment: [Click here to learn](http://bfy.tw/4acA)

Answer (score 2):

This is not possible in 1.7.10 vanilla due to the severe lack of command features, namely the `@e` selector.

I would highly recommend upgrading to a more recent version. For example, in 1.8, the `@e` selector was introduced in order to target non-player entities with commands, as well as the ability to add mobs to a scoreboard team. If a mob is in the same team as a player, that mob will no longer be hostile towards that player but will remain hostile towards non-teammates.

```
/scoreboard teams add Passive
/scoreboard teams join Passive @p @e[type=Zombie]
```

Comment: i would upgrade but the server i'm working on is running essentials and since essentials isn't available for 1.8 i'm stuck there>